# Kali Linux resolvconf symlinks broken after every reboot

Tags: kali-linux, resolv.conf, resolvconf

I recently had to force my kali linux laptop to power off due to a desktop freeze. Now, after every reboot, DNS resolving is broken for browsers and tools like `apt-get` and `ping`, even though tools like `dig` still work for manual resolving. After every reboot I fix it like this:

First I verify that most of the symlinks are there as expected:

```
$ ls -altrh /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Apr 17 23:40 /etc/resolv.conf -> /etc/resolvconf/run/resolv.conf

$ ls -altrh /etc/resolvconf/run
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Apr 17 23:40 /etc/resolvconf/run -> /run/resolvconf
```

Then I verify that the previous configuration is still available:

```
$ cat /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Then I have to create a missing directory which one of the aforementioned symlinks is trying to point to:

```
$ sudo mkdir /run/resolvconf/
```

And finally, I have to create the missing `resolv.conf` file inside the directory I created, and populate the file with the nameserver info that was preserved in the file I checked earlier:

```
$ sudo touch /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
$ sudo cp /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

Now DNS resolving works for any and all programs.

**Question:** Before I go and write a startup script to automate this workaround, does anyone know how I can stop having to do this ever again? I can't figure out why this is happening. Thank you.

System info:

```
$ cat /etc/debian_version 
Kali Linux Rolling
$ uname -a
Linux foobar 4.9.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.18-1kali1 (2017-04-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue with my Kali install, originally I thought it was the VPN software I installed but after some research it seems to be an issue with Kali.

An easier solution for the issue that I have been using is: `sudo apt-get purge resolvconf`

Then directly after that run `sudo apt-get install resolvconf`

Unfortunately as of now I have to do this every boot but I had the same thought as you to make a startup script to automatically purge and re-install the resolvconf file. Using those two commands would be a bit easier than re creating the missing directory by hand, and possibly make writing a start up script easier.

Comment: You do not have to `sudo apt-get install resolvconf` just `sudo apt-get purge resolvconf` and restart the computer. While shutting down Kali will automatically fix the problems and the next time you login you will have internet access without having to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I solved enabling and starting resolvconf manually with

```
sudo systemctl enable resolvconf
sudo systemctl start resolvconf
```

Now name resolving works after boot. Maybe Kali disabling resolvconf as service...

Comment: Maybe to do with https://docs.kali.org/policy/kali-linux-network-service-policies ?

Answer (score 0):

I just made a simple bash script in my root folder...

```
touch netresolv.sh
vim netresolv.sh
```

//substitute fav editor for `vim`

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf && echo "nameserver 1.1.1.1" >> /etc/resolv.conf && service 
NetworkManager restart && exit
```

//save and exit text-editor

```
chmod +x netresolv.conf
```

right now I just execute it manually after login each time as I am researching how and where to add the script to run automatically after each restart upon logging in...

Can anyone tell me how to take this script the rest of the way? I don't want it running before login because that'd connect the web before root was logged in thus making it vulnerable or would it?  Do I add it as a `cron` job? or as a `systemd` service? or add to `~/.profile`?