# Reconfigure network-manager on Kali Linux after installing openvpn or vpn-unlimited

Tags: kali-linux, networkmanager

From my [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452519/reconfigure-network-manager-on-kali-linux) that people closed because they could not answer it:

> I was trying to install openvpn from this
>   [tutorial](https://www.kali-linux.fr/configuration/installer-open-vpn-sous-kali-linux)
>   and unlimited vpn from
>   [here](https://www.vpnunlimitedapp.com/en/info/manuals/linux). I had
>   internet but, when I shutdown my computer and turn it back on, I
>   cannot have Internet access even if I'm connecting to the wifi. It's
>   not a hardware problem because when I try the live cd, I have internet
>   access.
>
> How to fix that?

Here is the solution.

Comment: It's Nice that you tried to understand the problem but with explanation you gave it's very unlikely that anyone undertand it sometime. Thank you for the effort but you better learn any other Linux before using Kali

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem after removing the vpn packages (did not fix the problem) and some researches about internet access error and tying to reconfigure `network-manager` which was impossible on my OS giving me permission denied even with `SU`. On the posts people talked a lot about configuring DNS in the file `/etc/resolv.conf`, and when I try to edit it, I could not, I went to the `/etc/` folder looking for it, it was there but I clicked on it, I got error `broken link`. I tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` then restart my computer but nothing happened, still broken.

I got on that [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/359644/kali-linux-resolvconf-symlinks-broken-after-every-reboot/383461) and just executed `sudo apt purge resolvconf`, it said needed to reboot, I just reboot the computer, when rebooting the Kali had some job running, I let it then, when it starts up I could have internet access.

It was the openVPN or vpn-unlimited who broke the network configuration.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441684/question-about-why-dns-resolv-conf-stopped-working/441689 That is one of the solutions some advanced users prefer mainly in server VMs environment, the other would be fixing up the resolv.conf broken link. I however advise trying to understand what you are doing besides following blindly links. Trying to install client VPN software and even a service like Unlimited VPN without possibly understanding it is a paid service, is not a good sign.

Comment: ....However congrats for trying. I am not advising you should not try new things, just that you need to investigate a little better and think about you are trying to do.